# change list items depend on day (flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, parse-platform

I have a specific list in my app for each user :

```
Future<void> getServerMeals(String userName) async {
    final QueryBuilder<ParseObject> parseQuery =
        QueryBuilder<ParseObject>(ParseObject('UsersEaten'));

    parseQuery.whereContains('eatenBy', userName);

    final ParseResponse apiResponse = await parseQuery.query();

    if (apiResponse.success && apiResponse.results != null) {
      List<dynamic>? apiRes = apiResponse.results;

      List<dynamic> newMeals = apiRes!
          .map((e) => EatenItem(
              id: e['objectId'],
              eatenCal: e['eatenCal'],
              eatenTitle: e['eatenTitle'],
              eatenImageUrl: e['eatenImg'],
              userId: e['objectId']))
          .toList();
      _eatenMeals = newMeals;
      print(apiResponse.results);
    }
  }
```

now I want to empty this list items every day and allow users to access previous day list how do I do that?

Comment: Store the meals in a list and create a method where you can get all meals of today

Answer (score 0):

Create a shared_preference to hold the previous day list, a shared_preference to hold day number and a variable(can also be shared_preference or whatever you want) to hold today list.

On app launch, make a verification to check if day number has changed. For example, the last day number is 26, today it must be 27.Then save your current list into shared_preference as previous day list and now you can empty you current list.

Comment: I want to store List items on my parse server not locally

Comment: The process is the same. Just adapt it to fit your needs.Whether it is the shared_preferences or on a server, the important thing is to save your data and be capable to retrieve it.